# Check rectangle inside rectangle in python

Tags: python, rectangles

I am a newbie in python. 
Can some one tell me how can I check a small rectangle (with two coordinates) is inside another Rectangle(with two coordinates) in Python.

Comment: How would you check it without python?

Comment: in c#, there are several direct functions to check. but i am really confused how to do it in python.
what will be the right module to use it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you state what co-ordinate system you are using, how your rectangle is defined, and what is considered inside a rectangle. For example, if two rectangles have identical co-ordinates is this considered "inside" or not? etc Basically, your question doesn't give enough information to give a robust / non-buggy answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working on a game. I suggest you use Pygame. I assume you are talking about collision checking for the use of sprite rectangles? Anyway here's an algorithm to check for collision between two rectangles. I am not writing a function for you to copy paste and use it in your program. This is just logic for you to understand and for you to write a piece of code by yourself to write from this logic depending on your application.

```
def check_collision(  A,  B )
{

#If any of the sides from A are outside of B
if( bottomA <= topB )
{
    return false;
}

if( topA >= bottomB )
{
    return false;
}

if( rightA <= leftB )
{
    return false;
}

if( leftA >= rightB )
{
    return false;
}

#If none of the sides from A are outside B
return true;
}
```

Comment: This is not valid python.

Comment: i am working on text extraction of PDF. I have extracted text in XML format with each characters coordinates. On UI, user create a Zone(rectangle) to mark text as suppose heading.
I have to get coordinates from UI and get text from XML. to create HTML element as Heading.

I hope i am clear enough.

Comment: @dominik Did you even read the comment? It's an algorithm/logic for rectangle collision detection. NOT a python code.

Comment: @kotAPI Sorry, I commented before you edited your answer and added the comment that it's only pseudocode.

Answer (score 8):

You could write something like

```
def contains(r1, r2):
   return r1.x1 < r2.x1 < r2.x2 < r1.x2 and r1.y1 < r2.y1 < r2.y2 < r1.y2
```

However, the exact code depends on the encoding of your rectangle. I am assuming that each rectangle is defined by two points in the upper left (`(x1|y1)`) and lower right corner (`(x2|y2)`) and that your rectangles are not rotated.

If you use a tuple (such as `((1,2),(2,4))`) as your representation of rectangles, you will have to access the fields by index. I highly recommend that you use named tuples (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: ...(and that `x/y1` is used for the upper left and `x/y2` for the lower right corner)

Comment: what object are r1, r2 here?

Comment: @PMishra In python it doesn't really matter what kind of object it is. Any object that has the properties explained above will work. This is called duck typing.